# Passing the output of an asynchronous function to gulp.dest?

Tags: node.js, gulp

In my **gulp** task, I just need to copy a file obtained from a previous task to a dest path that I have to determine at runtime using an asynchronous function (because I use `fs` functions).

How do I do this? How do I feed the result of an asynchronous function to a `gulp.dest` directive?

#### Sample code:

```
function getDest() {
  fs.readdir('my/path', function(error, contents) {
    // pick the right one
    return the_right_one;
  })
}

gulp.task('copy-stuff', ['previous-task'], function() {
  return gulp.src('some/file').pipe(gulp.dest(getDest()));
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this as with any other async node/javascript code, by using callbacks.

For instance:

```
function getDest(cb) {
  fs.readdir('my/path', function(error, contents) {
    // pick the right one
    cb(the_right_one);
  })
}

gulp.task('copy-stuff', ['previous-task'], function() {
  getDest(function(properDest) {
    gulp.src('some/file')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(properDest));
  })
})
```

Note, in this example we don't return the stream or a promise, so you'll have some troubles using dependencies (this would finish before the a dependant would start). To solve this we can either return a promise that is resolved on end or simply use the callback given to the task.

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
gulp.task('copy-stuff', ['previous-task'], function(callback) {
  getDest(function(properDest) {
    gulp.src('some/file')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(properDest))
        .on('end', callback)
  })
})
```

You can see more of the Orchestrator (the task runner gulp is using) API in [the documentation](https://github.com/orchestrator/orchestrator#api) or see the [gulp documentation with async examples](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support).

Answer (score 3):

In 3.8 you can pass a function to `gulp.dest` that returns the destination for the file. This function has to be synchronous, so you could do

```
gulp.src('some/file')
  .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
      return 'build/' + fs.readFileSync('file_containing_target_dir');
  }));
```